# Copy files from AWS S3 to Azure storage archive tier

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-storage, azcopy

I'm trying to copy files from AWS S3 to Azure storage archive access tier directly. Using `azcopy` I can copy the files from S3 to Azure but when using `--block-blob-tier Archive` flag I hit the error:

```
failed to parse user input due to error: blob-tier is not supported while copying from sevice to service
```

The only way around this I can find is to either download the files locally and then upload to Azure or change the access tier once uploaded. The first is the better solution as with the second it would be twice the cost (pay for the write operation when changing tier). Does anyone have another option or know why `azcopy` doesn't support this?

azcopy error: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/blob/7eb7b49f1354b7c205dd469c1ac18cb12f7d353a/cmd/copy.go#L557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downloading files from S3 to your local computer and then uploading it back to Azure Storage, you can simply copy the file from S3 to Azure Storage without explicitly setting the blob access tier. The resulting blob's access tier would be `Hot`. Once the copy operation completes successfully, you can change the access tier.

The advantage of this approach is that the copying happens directly between S3 and Azure Storage. However this process is asynchronous and you must wait for the copy operation to complete (instead of just getting it accepted) before initiating the access tier change operation.

**UPDATE**

If copying directly from S3 to Azure Blob Storage and then changing access tier is not practical for you from cost perspective, you can download the object from S3 and upload directly in Azure Blob Storage Archive tier. This feature is in preview as of writing of this post. This feature is available in Storage REST API version 2019-02-02. From the [`release notes link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/version-2019-02-02):

> The Copy Blob, Put Block List, and Put Blob APIs support the
>   x-ms-access-tier header for Block Blobs, to set the tier on the result
>   without needing a second API call.

Comment: My problem with that is the additional cost required to move files into Archive tier. Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal#blob-level-tiering-billing) I would pay to upload the files and then also be charged the write operation cost to transfer those into archive

Comment: Understood. Updated my answer to include direct uploading into archive tier.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Flexify.io portal in which you need to add the s3 bucket credentials and azure blob storage and key then copy from s3 to block and vice versa is allowed. even move of data is